# over(partition by )by Function in DPLYR

Tags: dplyr

How to write R code for executing a partition by function

Suppose for example a customer does numerous transactions a day and i have to find the second highest transaction done by a customer on a particular day using partition by function using dplyr .

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may normally do this in SQL (SQL Server?). With DPLYR you can do this with a grouping, there's not a need for the equivalent of a window function.

`data %>% group_by(customer) %>% arrange(txn_amount) %>% slice(2) %>% ungroup`

Group by customer; sort by transaction amount; and then "slice" the 2 entry in each group.

Be wary of situations where customers only have one transaction.